# Predefined lists in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `Member` model with two state machines, `state` and `account`. I'd like to use `factory_girl` to create a predefined list of all possible state and account combinations in my tests.

For example, with the following combinations:

```
combinations = [
  [:state_a, :account_a], [:state_a, :account_b], [:state_a, :account_c],
  [:state_b, :account_a], [:state_b, :account_b], [:state_b, :account_c],
  [:state_c, :account_a], [:state_c, :account_b], [:state_c, :account_c]
]
```

I'd like some kind of helper, e.g. `create_list_for_all_states_and_accounts` which would create:

```
[
  Member(state: 'a', account: 'a'),
  Member(state: 'a', account: 'b'),
  Member(state: 'a', account: 'c'),
  Member(state: 'b', account: 'a'),
  # ...
]
```

Is this possible in `factory_girl`?

Comment: It's not usual. factory_girl is about creating single instances. Or were you thinking of precreating all those instances and returning them one at at a time from a factory method?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth was mainly thinking of creating instances for all combos and then testing my scopes, e.g. `expect(Member.some_scope).to ...`

Comment: You mean Member.some_scope returns one of the instances you created? That sounds like Rails fixtures, not factories. (Lots of discussion on that elsewhere on SO.)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth you're probably right about that. I use factory_girl everywhere else and was kinda hoping I could do it all in one place.

Comment: Mixing fixtures with factories may become painful. If your states are related, there are state machine gems out there (i.e. https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) that will help you to define your model without needing to consider each value every time you create an instance. Have you also considered traits? It would be a bit of initial work to define each of those combinations as a trait, but you would then be able to create(:member :combination_a), etc.

Comment: @dsatch I am indeed using `state_machine` but the behaviours differ greatly depending on the state/account combinations. I'm also using traits (defined using iteration) but it'd be nice to be able to create an instance of each. Right now, I've just defined a helper in my spec.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution as suggested in the comments would be to define a helper method in a file in `spec/support` with your helper method, and then use it in your specs wherever you need it:

```
def create_list_for_all_states_and_accounts(states = %w[ a b c ], accounts = %w[ a b c ])
  states.product(accounts).map do |state, account|
    Member.create(state: state, account: account)
  end
end
```

Or if you always have the same state and account names you can do this:

```
def create_list_for_all_states_and_accounts(names = %w[ a b c ])
  names.repeated_permutation(2).map do |state, account|
    Member.create(state: state, account: account)
  end
end
```

If you really do want to use FactoryGirl to create your instances using traits, you can define a factory like this:

```
factory :member do
  %w[ a b c ].product(%w[ a b c ]).each do |state, account|
    trait :"state_#{state}_account_#{account}" do
      state     state
      account   account
    end
  end
end
```

Which would enable you to create instances like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:member, :state_a_account_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something somewhat hacky, but robust and efficient to do this. I wanted to use factory_girl to create a set of bundles, which are basically seed data (but since I used database_cleaner in tests, I could not just use `seed.rb`). Here is how I did:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bundle do
    factory :all_bundles do
      price  1
      name   "bronze"

      after :create do
        FactoryGirl.create :silver_bundle
        FactoryGirl.create :gold_bundle
        FactoryGirl.create :platinum_bundle
      end
    end

    factory :silver_bundle do
      price  2
      name   "silver"
    end

    factory :gold_bundle do
      price  3
      name   "gold"
    end

    factory :platinum_bundle do
      price  4
      name   "platinum"
    end
  end
end
```

After that, I call `create :all_bundles`, and I'm done.

So the idea here is:

1. define all your factories
2. in the first one, add an `after :create` block (and/or an `after :stub` one if you need one) that call other factories

Note that the `after :create` block should be in a subfactory (`all_bundles` here) and not in the parent factory (`bundle`), or each subfactory will execute it :)